# Темная тема data-Attribute

Tags: javascript, css

вот мой код.  при клике на кнопку он подменяет в data-theme c default на dark.  просьба указать на мою ошибку почему не происходит подмена на обратное значение. почему не сменяеться значение через setAttribute ?

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click' , changeTheme , false);

function changeTheme() {
    var child = document.querySelector('.child');
    if( child.dataset.theme == "dark"){  /*проверка чему равен атребут*/
        child.setAttribute("data-theme", "default")
    }
 
    
    
    child.dataset.theme= "dark";
   
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root, [data-theme="default"] {
  --color-primary: blue;
  /* Цветовой контраст */
  --color-bg: white;
  --color-contrast-lower: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
  --color-contrast-low: hsl(240, 1%, 83%);
  --color-contrast-medium: hsl(240, 1%, 48%);
  --color-contrast-high: hsl(240, 4%, 20%);
  --color-contrast-higher: black;
}

[data-theme] {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-contrast-high);
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --color-primary: red;
  /* Цветовой контраст */
  --color-bg: black;
  --color-contrast-lower: hsl(240, 6%, 15%);
  --color-contrast-low: hsl(252, 4%, 25%);
  --color-contrast-medium: hsl(240, 1%, 57%);
  --color-contrast-high: hsl(0, 0%, 89%);
  --color-contrast-higher: white;
}

button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section data-theme="dark">
  
    <div class="child" data-theme="default">
        <h1>Английский перевод 1914 года, H. Rackham</h1>

<p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful."</p>
  </div>
</section>

<button>Click.</button>
```

Comment: странный выбор способа задания темы. почему дата атрибут, а не класс? тем более, что через какой нить `.data('theme')/dataset` еще и работать не будет, вероятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

условие смены цвета в js не прописано..всегда в темную тему ставило

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click' , changeTheme , false);

function changeTheme() {
    var child = document.querySelector('.child');
    if( child.dataset.theme == "dark"){  /*проверка чему равен атребут*/
        child.setAttribute("data-theme", "default")
    }
    else{
        child.dataset.theme= "dark";
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root, [data-theme="default"] {
  --color-primary: blue;
  /* Цветовой контраст */
  --color-bg: white;
  --color-contrast-lower: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
  --color-contrast-low: hsl(240, 1%, 83%);
  --color-contrast-medium: hsl(240, 1%, 48%);
  --color-contrast-high: hsl(240, 4%, 20%);
  --color-contrast-higher: black;
}

[data-theme] {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-contrast-high);
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --color-primary: red;
  /* Цветовой контраст */
  --color-bg: black;
  --color-contrast-lower: hsl(240, 6%, 15%);
  --color-contrast-low: hsl(252, 4%, 25%);
  --color-contrast-medium: hsl(240, 1%, 57%);
  --color-contrast-high: hsl(0, 0%, 89%);
  --color-contrast-higher: white;
}

button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section data-theme="dark">
  
    <div class="child" data-theme="default">
        <h1>Английский перевод 1914 года, H. Rackham</h1>

<p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful."</p>
  </div>
</section>

<button>Click.</button>
```

Comment: спасибо. хоть я сейчас и понимаю,что это элементарно.